# Symlinks copy to Samba via gvfs is not working

Tags: server, samba, symbolic-link

I use default app of Ubuntu 20.04 - [Files](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Files). I use it for Samba connection. I propose that connection use `gvfs`. Also I use Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server.

My problem is that I try to copy some symlinks from client to server I get error - "Symlinks not supported by backend".

Also when I use MC for copy and try to copy to `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=cool.local,share=dir` I have another error "Operation not supported (95)".

I want to keep symlinks at server, symlinks have to have relative path (for ex. ./dir2, not /mnt/dir2) and symlinks have to work when I try to connect via Files (`Samba`, `gvfs`) at client PC.

I use Samba version 4.11.6-Ubuntu.

Any ideas are welcome.

My samba config:

```
[global]
        workgroup = LAN
        bind interfaces only = yes
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        log level = 0
        syslog = 0
        netbios name = COOL
        server string = "Cool Server"
        map to guest = Bad User
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        security = user
        encrypt passwords = yes
        hosts allow = 127.0.0.0/24 192.168.1.0/24
        min protocol = SMB3
        name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
        acl allow execute always = yes

[APPs]
        valid users = @group
        path = /path/to/dir
        write list = @group
        comment = Directories
        create mode = 0660
        directory mode = 0770
        browseable = yes
```

Comment: A bit old but may help you.https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html

Comment: @David I try to add `follow symlinks = yes` and `wide links = no` to config to share dir but it not work. :( `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'test-link.py': Operation not supported`

Comment: Maybe a problem with the filesystem , does the filesytem support symlinks?

Comment: @mook765 I have `ext4` at both PC.

Comment: I found solve. Link is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1337257/clients-cant-create-symlinks-on-samba-share). This help for me.